# React : How to get tand display total number of products?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to get the count of the total no of products. I am fetching data from list of products and displaying the list. How can I get the count of products? When I add or delete the product, the product number changes, it works fine but when the page is loaded for the first time if there is data in the backend (list of products), it still gives a count of 0. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

---

### ListProducts.js

```
import { makeStyles, Paper, Card, CardActions, CardContent, Typography,CardMedia,CardActionArea } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import FormProduct from './FormProduct'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add'
import Button from '../../components/controls/Button'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addProduct, listAllProducts, deleteProduct, editProduct } from '../../actions'
import PopUp from '../controls/PopUp'
import ConfirmDialog from '../controls/ConfirmDialog'
import laptop from '../../laptop.jpg'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    pageContent: {
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
        padding: theme.spacing(5)
    },
    pageContent1: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
        background: 'rgb(63,94,251)',
        background: 'radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63,94,251,1) 0%, rgba(170,70,252,1) 100%)'
    },
    newButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '100px',
        top: '120px'
    },
    root: {
        minWidth: 275,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 14,
    },
    pos: {
        marginBottom: 12,
    }
}))


const ListProducts = (props) => {
    const [openPopUp, setOpenPopUp] = useState(false)
    const [confirmDialog, setConfirmDialog] = useState({ isOpen: false, title: '' })
    const [edited, setEdited] = useState(null)
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const classes = useStyles()
    const addOrEdit = (product) => {
        if (product.id == 0) {
            props.addProduct(product)
            setCounter(counter + 1)
        }
        else {
            props.editProduct(product.id, product)
        }
        setOpenPopUp(false)
    }
    const renderProduct = (id) => {
        props.deleteProduct(id)
        setConfirmDialog(false)
        if(counter > 0){
            setCounter(counter - 1)
        }
        else{
            setCounter(0)
        }
    }
    const openInPopUp = (product) => {
        setEdited(product)
        setOpenPopUp(true)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        props.listAllProducts()
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
                <Typography variant='h5' component='h5'>All Products({counter})</Typography>
                <Button text='Add Product'
                    variant='outlined'
                    startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                    className={classes.newButton}
                    onClick={() => setOpenPopUp(true)} />
            </Paper>
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent1}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    {props.products && props.products.map((product, index) => {
                        return <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} key={index + 1}>
                            <Card className={classes.root}>
                                <CardActionArea>
                                    <CardMedia
                                        component="img"
                                        alt="Laptop"
                                        height="140"
                                        image={laptop}
                                        title="Laptop"
                                    />
                                    <CardContent>
                                        <Typography variant='h3' component='h3' className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                            Product Name : {product.name}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography variant='h5' component='h5'>
                                            Product Description : {product.description}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                                            Product Price : {product.price}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                                            Product Category : {product.category}
                                        </Typography>
                                    </CardContent>
                                    </CardActionArea>
                                    <CardActions>
                                        <Button text='Edit' variant='outlined'
                                            onClick={() => openInPopUp(product)} />
                                        <Button text='Delete' variant='outlined'
                                            onClick={() => setConfirmDialog({
                                                isOpen: true, onConfirmDialog: () => renderProduct(product.id),
                                                title: `Are you sure you want to delete this product? : ${product.name}`
                                            })}
                                        />
                                    </CardActions>
                            </Card>
                            </Grid>
                        })}
                </Grid>
            </Paper>
                <PopUp openPopUp={openPopUp}
                    setOpenPopUp={setOpenPopUp}
                    title='Product Form'>
                    <FormProduct
                        addOrEdit={addOrEdit}
                        edited={edited}
                        title='Hello'
                         />
                </PopUp>
                <ConfirmDialog title={confirmDialog.title}
                    confirmDialog={confirmDialog}
                    setConfirmDialog={setConfirmDialog}
                />
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { products: Object.values(state.products).reverse() }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { listAllProducts: listAllProducts, addProduct: addProduct,deleteProduct:deleteProduct,editProduct:editProduct })(ListProducts)
```

---

### actions.js

```
export const listAllProducts=()=>{
    return async (dispatch)=>{
        const response=await products.get('/products')
        dispatch({
            type:LIST_ALL_PRODUCTS,
            payload:response.data
        })
    }
}
```

---

### reducer.js

```
import {LIST_ALL_PRODUCTS} from '../actions/types'
import _ from 'lodash'

const productsReducer=(state={},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case LIST_ALL_PRODUCTS:
            return {...state,..._.mapKeys(action.payload,'id')}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default productsReducer
```

Comment: Where you set the counter for the number of products ? Like `setCounter(props.products.length)` ?

Comment: I'm just incrementing and decrementing the counter when the product is added and deleted.